# How to replace a Date that I add to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, date

```
ArrayList member = new ArrayList();

member.add(new Member("V0001","Amy","0000-0000-0000","012-3456789","01-01-2014","01-01-   2015"));

private String memberId=V0001;
private String memberName=Amy;
private String icNo = 0000-0000-0000;
private String hpNo = 012-3456789;
private String joiningDate = 01-01-2014;
private String expiredDate = 01-01-2015;
System.out.printf("\nEnter New Expired Date: ");
String expiredDate =inputS12.nextLine();

member.get(inputS12).set(6,"expiredDate"); // This is the problem
```

The problem now is, I can enter the new expired date which is ("01-01-2016") that I want, but the new expired date did not change to 01-01-2016, it still remains 01-01-2015.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: yup,i using jcreator to write

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/mIbDs0p.png you can try check the picture,i just dont know how to set the expiredDate i enter to store in the Array.

Comment: Anyone can help me solve this problem?

Comment: @Xiao: Post your complete code. Are you new to collections?? Seems you are not setting member properly.

Comment: i am new member,i have a problem with post code,do u mind give me your email,i can easily email u my code

Comment: Still cant solve my problem==

Comment: seems like  a basic mistake in understanding how java classes work? you are modifying a local variable and not the member variable.

Comment: @Markus Mikkoleinen Do u mind gv me your email,i send u my code?

Comment: i just screenshoot a part of my code.I using manual function to type in the date,so after i type in the new expired date,i want the new expired date i typed replace the old expired date.now the problem is,the new expired date i type cant replace the old expired date.
http://imgur.com/SftoypQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full code:

```
ArrayList member = new ArrayList();
member.add(new Member("V0001","Amy","0000-0000-0000","012-3456789","01-01-2014","01-01-2015"));
System.out.printf("\nEnter New Expired Date: ");
String expiredDate =inputS12.nextLine();
Member m=(Member)member.get(0);//First you need to get the object
m.setExpiredDate(expiredDate);
member.set(0,m);
```

Answer (score 1):

with your code

```
member.get(index);
```

will return you a `Member` object.

If you have a public setter for `expiredDate`

you should be able to do

```
member.get(index).setExpiredDate (new Date ());
```

To make this work better I recommend you to also do

```
ArrayList <Member> member = new ArrayList <Member> ();
```

Comment: i used private `String expiredDate;`

`public void setexpiredDate(String expiredDate)
`{
   this.expiredDate = expiredDate;
}`

`public String getexpiredDate()`
`{
   return expiredDate;`
}`

Comment: yup ,your codes help me also,i adding this 
ArrayList <Member> member = new ArrayList <Member> (); to my code

Answer (score 0):

If you use java, I hope following codes will get done the job you want.

Your Member class should be like this:

package stackoverflow;

public class Member {

```
private String memberId;
private String memberName;
private String icNo;
private String hpNo;
private String joiningDate;
private String expireDate;
```

///Setters

```
public void setMemberId(String memberId) {
    this.memberId = memberId;
}

public void setMemberName(String memberName) {
    this.memberName = memberName;
}

public void setIcNo(String icNo) {
    this.icNo = icNo;
}

public void setHpNo(String hpNo) {
    this.hpNo = hpNo;
}

public void setJoiningDate(String joiningDate) {
    this.joiningDate = joiningDate;
}

public void setExpireDate(String expireDate) {
    this.expireDate = expireDate;
}

////Getters
public String getMemberId() {
    return memberId;
}

public String getMemberName() {
    return memberName;
}

public String getIcNo() {
    return icNo;
}

public String getHpNo() {
    return hpNo;
}

public String getJoiningDate() {
    return joiningDate;
}

public String getExpireDate() {
    return expireDate;
}
```

}

## Following code will show you how your job get done.

package stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    **//Create ArrayList to hold the list of members**

    ArrayList<Member> memberList = new ArrayList();

    **//Create new member**

    Member member = new Member();

    **//Adding new member's info**

    member.setMemberId("V0001");
    member.setMemberName("Amy");
    member.setIcNo("0000-0000-0000");
    member.setHpNo("012-3456789");
    member.setJoiningDate("01-01-2014");
    member.setExpireDate("01-01-2015");

    **//Adding newly created member to memberList**

    memberList.add(member);

    **//Checking expire date before you change it.
    //here you should know the index of the member object which you
    //want to update or view values of it .Here in case its 0**

    System.out.println(((Member) memberList.get(0)).getExpireDate());
    //
    **//Adding new expire date to the member need to do the following steps.**
    String newExpireDate = "01-01-2016";

    **//Getting Object you want to update value and updat it**

    ((Member) memberList.get(0)).setExpireDate(newExpireDate);

    **//Checking the values after updating the expire date.**

    System.out.println(((Member) memberList.get(0)).getExpireDate());

}
```

}